# circulate Jquery + mouseover/mouseout event

Tags: javascript, animation, events, onmouseover, onmouseout

i'm trying to use .circulate
i'd like the animation stop ( pause )/continue   when onmouseover/onmouseout

here is the code from  https://css-tricks.com/examples/Circulate/

```
html:

<div id="sphere-area" >
<img src="a.png" alt="ball" id="orange-ball" />
alt="" />
</div>



Js:

function startBallOne() {
$("#orange-ball").circulate({
    speed: 4000,
    height: 100,
    width: -880,
    sizeAdjustment: 40,
    loop: true,
    zIndexValues: [1, 1, 3, 3]
});
}
```

i tried

```
$("#orange-ball").mouseout(circulate(...
```

or

```
$("#orange-ball").mouseover(function(){
$(this).circulate
```

but nothing work ..

Any ideas ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

just try to put your JS code inside `$(doument).ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function startBallOne() {
        $("#orange-ball").circulate({
            speed: 4000,
            height: 100,
            width: -880,
            sizeAdjustment: 40,
            loop: true,
            zIndexValues: [1, 1, 3, 3]
        });
    }
});
```